# Display color representation quality (IPS vs VA technology)

Tags: display

I always thought that IPS is superior in colors (and viewing angles) to the VA panels. However, I'm now buying a monitor, and as I was reading about various parameters, I've come across color gamuts and HDR. I've noticed that many cheaper VA displays have better percentages on measured color gamuts (sRGB, Adobe RGB and DCI-P3) and higher number HDR (with same viewing angles - usually 178° both vertically and horizontally).

Am I missing something, or is color quality primarily dependent on those and is no longer "bound" to the IPS technology?

(I am aware that VA can have black smearing issues and also probably worse blur but I'm currently only focusing on color quality - connected also with viewing angle because it can affect it a lot.)